# Algorithm answering to 'possibility of building a triangle' queries

Tags: algorithm, tree

Firstly I would like to apologize for my English and the title. The problem is that I have an array of numbers A (max size of array is 10^6). Every number is smaller than 10^9. I have 10^5 queries consisting of two numbers: a and b. I have to tell if there are three numbers k1, k2, k3 on the [a, b] interval of the array A that:

1. k1 + k2 > k3
2. k1 + k3 > k2
3. k2 + k3 > k1

(so is it possible to build a triangle using them).
I know that I can sort an interval and check it but it is too slow O(q * n logn). I consider that it is necessary to do this exercise offline. I thought about the MO's algorithm but I don't know how to check if after removing an element, will be a triangle. Maybe any tree structure, but I have no idea. Can you help me resolve this problem?

Link to exercise: https://main.edu.pl/pl/archive/ontak/2009/tro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a sorted array `a[0], ..., a[k-1]`. We only need to take every triple of neighbor elements and check if it is a triangle. There is no point in checking other triples.

If there are no triangles in the array then we know for sure that `2 * a[i] <= a[i+2]` for every `i < k-2`. We can notice that elements of an array without triangles should grow relatively fast.

Now let's build the "worst" sorted array without triangles:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...
```

Looks familiar. A Fibonacci sequence. Our numbers could not be larger than `10^9`. On the other hand, 45th Fibonacci number is greater than `10^9`.

Thus, for every interval with a length exceeding 45, the answer is positive. For smaller intervals, we can use an ordered set data structure with `O(log(n))` insert operation and a possibility to iterate several steps forward and backward from the position of insertion (for example, `std::set` in c++). Or simply copy this small interval, sort it and check for triangles with a linear search.

The complexity of this algorithm is `O(q)`.